# Are there always non-parallel bundle morphisms which preserve metricity?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, symmetry, connections

> Let $(E,\nabla^E),(F,\nabla^F)$ be smooth vector bundles over a manifold $M$. We say a bundle isomorphism $\Phi:E \to F$ **preserves metricity** if it "sends" $\nabla^E$-compatible metrics to $\nabla^F$-compatible metrics.

(By "sends" I mean "induces in the natural way" via pullback).

> We say $\Phi$ **respects the connections** if $\nabla_x^F (\Phi(s))=\Phi( \nabla_x^E s)$ for every $s \in \Gamma(E),X \in \Gamma(TM)$

(or equivalently $\Phi$ is $\nabla^{E^* \otimes F}$-**parallel**: $\nabla^{E^* \otimes F}\Phi=0$, where $\nabla^{E^* \otimes F}$ is the tensor product connection of $\nabla^E,\nabla^F$).

*It's clear that every bundle isomorphism which respects the connections, preserves metricity.*

(Since then, for any $\nabla^E$-compatible metric $\eta$, $\Phi:(E,\nabla^E,\eta) \to (F,\nabla^F,\phi_*\eta)$ preserves all the structure).

> **Question:** Are there **always** bundle isomorphisms which preserve metricity, but do not respect the connections?

(There are trivial cases where this holds, e.g when $\nabla^E$ has no compatible metrics. This seems to be interesting when there are "many" $\nabla^E$-compatible metrics).

*An equivalent formulation:*

A short calculation shows $\Phi$ preserves metricity if and only if

$$ \langle (\nabla_x \Phi)(s),\Phi(t)  \rangle_{\Phi_*\eta} + \langle \Phi(s),(\nabla_x \Phi)(t)  \rangle_{\Phi_*\eta} =0$$ for **every** $\nabla^E$-compatible metric $\eta$.

($s,t$ are sections of $E$).

Equivalently: $ \langle (\nabla_x \Phi)(t),\Phi(t)  \rangle_{\Phi_*\eta}  =0 \iff \langle \Phi^{-1}(\nabla_x \Phi)(t),t  \rangle_{\eta}  =0$

Denoting $\Psi=\Phi^{-1}(\nabla_x \Phi):(E,\eta) \to (E,\eta)$, we conclude $\Phi$ preserves metricity if and only if

$$\langle \Psi(t),t  \rangle_{\eta}  =0 $$ which is equivalent to $\Psi^T=-\Psi$ (where the transpose is taken w.r.t $\eta$).

> Thus, $\Phi$ **preserves metricity** iff $\Phi^{-1}(\nabla_x \Phi):E \to E$ is **skew-symmetric** w.r.t **every** $\nabla^E$-compatible metric $\eta$. (Note this metrics form a cone over $\mathbb{R}$).
>
> *So, the question amounts to the following:* Are there **always** bundle isomorphisms satisfying the above condition, but not parallel?

Comment: Isn't it possible in the setting of the question that there are no $\nabla^E$-compatible metrics so any vector bundle isomorphism would preserve metricity vacuously but won't necessarily respect the connections?

Comment: Of course, you are right. So, the question is inetersting only in cases where there are many $\nabla$-compatible metrics, so the constraint won't be trivial. BTW, this question is somehow related to our previous question on $\delta$, I will elaborate on that later. (I am not sure what is the "typical situation", that is how symmetric is a "random" connection? What is the maximal symmetry possible? (I asked here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/262357/how-large-can-the-cone-of-nabla-compatible-metrics-be)